# How do I stop Chrome window from being always on top?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome suddenly started hogging the desktop.  Once it is open it does not allow any other app to be on top.  It is quite annoying.  I researched the problem and the suggestion to use alt+space+c key works only momentarily.
Other suggestions included going back to default settings, but that would erase the history (which I find very useful at times) and other settings.
Is there another solution? 
Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Is it possible that you installed the always on top extension (or somehow got it installed)?  I know it sounds stupid.. but I thought I should mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+Space+c worked for me.  It closed all my open Google Chrome windows, but I just reopened, hit ctrl+shift+t to reopen the closed window and the problem seems to have gone away for now.

Comment: fwiw I ended up here cause I use Dexpot Window Manager (virtual window manager) and they have a menu option on each window menu (system menu / alt-space) - from which I could select "Always on top" to disable it.

googling a bit more gives you an array of addons that might do it - https://www.thewindowsclub.com/make-a-window-stay-always-on-top-windows.

there's an argument to I think it is SetWindowPos( ) in the Win32 API that let's you set this attribute per window, by Window handle.